# str - Function, Class or Method

Tags: python

I can write `'something '.strip()` and get `something` in return or I can type `str(8)` and get `'8'` in return. Also, `type ('a')` returns `str` as the response. Is `str` a function (which converted a numeric `8` to `'8'`) or a class, which has methods such as `strip()`, etc.?

Comment: `str` is a class. `str(8)` invokes the object constructor (not a function, but function-like) and returns an instance of `str` class

Comment: Go ahead and try it, write `type(str())` and `type(str().strip)`, also `type(str)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str - says it is a class. That doc refers to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str which describes the class. The Built-in Functions part of the docs clarifies `.. functions and types built into..`

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation; I really appreciate it! `type(str().strip)` responds with `builtin_function_or_method`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a class, whose constructor can get any Python object, and attempts to convert that to a string according to rules built-in the language.

The first thing it tries to do is to call the `__str__` method in the passed in object. If that does not exist, it tries to call the `__repr__` method. Whatever is returned is used as the new built string.

However, str is truly *the*  string class in Python, where all string methods are defined.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a class.  As seen in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

```
str(8) # returns '8'
```

Is creating an object of type `str`.  It calls `str`'s constructor.  Which in turn calls the objects `__str__` function.

As suggested in the comments, you can take a closer look at what's happens using the `type` keyword:

```
type(str)             # <class 'type'>
type(str())           # <class 'str'>
type('Hello, World!') # <class 'str'>
type(8)               # <class 'int'>
type(str(8))          # <class 'str'>
type(str().strip)     # <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```